# Using Elsa activities conductor

Tags: c#, workflow, .net-6.0, elsa-workflows

I have started to work with Elsa workflow. I want to use it for a document approval project. I use .net 6 and Elsa 2.6. Inspired by the document approval project available on the Elsa documentation, my project has two pages: one that sends documents, and another that lists the documents and has two buttons “Approve” and “Reject”. The first page has a form that sends the doc, the button “Send” of the form sends a request to the url of the http endpoint. Each document that is sent is an instance of the workflow. The second page of display has two buttons each button sends a signal. The application works fine. The documents are being sent and I can approve and reject with no problem.

Here is a screenshot of my workflow:

[image]
Recently, I discovered that Elsa has a nugget package called: Elsa.Activities.Conductor. From what I understood,  Conductor would help do an orchestration.

I am planning to add more workflows.
I installed the Elsa.Activities.Conductor.  But I still didn’t figure out how to use it, I tried to search for documentation but I could find much.  Here are my questions:

1. Would Elsa conductor be helpful in my use case?
2. Is Elsa conductor used for orchestrating workflows or activities or both? Like can I start and stop activities of my workflow using it? Or is it used just to orchestrate workflows (starting and stopping different workflows)?
3. How I can implement Elsa conductor?

Thank you in advance.